# how to use the local resource file with code behind page?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I want to make message strings independent of aspx file and code behind page

I want to know how to use the resource files with code behind to achieve this?

or is there any other way to do this, other than using resource files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In software, there is always more then one way. ;)
But if you want to separate string literals from an aspx page, resource (resx) files are the accepted standard.

[This article](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/prasham/RESOURCEFILES02132008080733AM/RESOURCEFILES.aspx) might help you get rolling.